# PAM module error (passing argument 1 of ‘snprintf’ discards ‘const’)

Tags: c, authentication, printf, pam

I have my PAM module:

I try to compile it, using string:

```
gcc -fPIC -DPIC -shared -rdynamic -o pam_test.so pam_test.c
```

But I have errors:

```
pam_test.c: In function ‘pam_sm_authenticate’:
pam_test.c:74:9: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘snprintf’ discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type [enabled by default]
         snprintf(msg[0].msg,60,"Second Password:%d:%d:%d:%d:",x1,x2,x3,x4);
         ^
In file included from pam_test.c:10:0:
/usr/include/stdio.h:386:12: note: expected ‘char * __restrict__’ but argument is of type ‘const char *’
 extern int snprintf (char *__restrict __s, size_t __maxlen,
```

module code:

```
#include <security/pam_modules.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>


#define PAM_SM_AUTH
#define MAX_V 30


PAM_EXTERN int pam_sm_authenticate(pam_handle_t * pamh, int flags, int argc, const char **argv)
{
        unsigned int ctrl;
        int retval;
        const char *name, *p;
        char *right;
        int x1,x2,x3,x4,y;

        time_t mytime;
        struct tm *mytm;

        mytime=time(0);
        mytm=localtime(&mytime);


        srandom(mytime);
        x1=random()%MAX_V;
        x2=random()%MAX_V;
        x3=random()%MAX_V;
        x4=random()%MAX_V;

        retval = pam_get_user(pamh, &name, "login: ");

        {
            struct pam_conv *conv;
            struct pam_message *pmsg[3],msg[3];
            struct pam_response *response;


        retval = pam_get_item( pamh, PAM_CONV, (const void **) &conv ) ;

        pmsg[0] = &msg[0];
        msg[0].msg_style = PAM_PROMPT_ECHO_OFF;
        msg[0].msg=malloc(100);
        snprintf(msg[0].msg,60,"Second Password:%d:%d:%d:%d:",x1,x2,x3,x4);

        retval = conv->conv(1, ( const struct pam_message ** ) pmsg
                            , &response, conv->appdata_ptr);
        y=2*x1*mytm->tm_mday+x3*mytm->tm_hour;
        right=malloc(100);
        snprintf(right,20,"%d",y);

        if (!(strcmp(right,response->resp))){
        return PAM_SUCCESS;
        }else{
        return PAM_AUTH_ERR;
        }
      }

        return PAM_SUCCESS;

}

PAM_EXTERN int pam_sm_setcred(pam_handle_t * pamh, int flags
                              ,int argc, const char **argv)
{
        unsigned int ctrl;
        int retval;
        retval = PAM_SUCCESS;
}

#ifdef PAM_STATIC
struct pam_module _pam_unix_auth_modstruct = {
    "pam_test",
    pam_sm_authenticate,
    pam_sm_setcred,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
};
#endif
```

Comment: The problem is you are passing a `const` thing to some function whose parameter has not declared as `const`.  This is not an error, just a warning that you loose the `const`ness of the thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that in `struct pam_message`, the `msg` field is declared as `const char*`; that is, a pointer to an immutable string. So you're not supposed to overwrite it with `snprintf`.

A simple workaround is to write the string before inserting a pointer to it into `msg`:

```
char *s = malloc(100);
snprintf(s, 100, "Second Password:%d:%d:%d:%d:",x1,x2,x3,x4);
msg[0].msg = s;
```

Note: You should check the return value of snprintf. If the value returned is more than 100, then the string was truncated.

Comment: Thank You, compile is successfully complete, but PAM is not work :(
In sys log I have message:
show_signal_msg: 9 callbacks suppressed
sshd[8868]: segfault at 0 ip 00007fb... sp 00007fb... error 4 in pam_test.so ...

Comment: @Igor-Potapov: I don't see anything obvious (aside from the fact that you never `free` any of the memory you `malloc`, but that won't cause a segfault, or at least not immediately), so I'm afraid you'll need to do some debugging. Good luck.

Comment: thank You again.
it will be better snprintf((char*)msg[0].msg,60,"Second Password:%d:%d:%d:%d:",x1,x2,x3,x4);
it work fine !!!